# Is this a weed, coming up right next to my vine, and if so what is it?

Tags: identification, weeds, vines

I found this shoot growing in northern NJ USA. It seemed to pop up and grow fast, as I don't remember seeing it a couple of days ago. It's already about a foot tall.

It's growing in a partially shaded area right next to a vining plant. The leaves are an odd shape and the stems are dark.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Looks vaguely like a peony.

Comment: @Ecnerwal it's near some peonies but doesn't look like them. Also didn't grow up red like my peonies. The stems behind it are from a clematis and it doesn't look like those either.

Comment: I Googled "three lobe weed leaf". Pick through these: https://www.google.com/search?q=three+lobe+weed+leaf&tbm=isch&tbo=u&source=univ&sa=X&ei=VPR1VcGNBtP3yQTT-YLoDQ&ved=0CC8QsAQ&biw=1173&bih=869

Comment: Maybe your Clematis was [grafted](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grafting) on the root system of another variety. Sometimes, the roots can grow new stems of their own, and suddenly you got two different plants sharing the same roots.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would guess that this 'weed' is a basal shoot from that large vine (which is some [*Clematis*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clematis) cultivar). You can see the fallen petals on the ground in the picture. Basal shoots are often different in color and form than top growth.